# Are quadprog and frontcon equivalent in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, finance

What exactly is the difference between [`quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/optim/ug/quadprog.html) and [`frontcon`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/finance/frontcon.html) in Matlab? For example if I use `quadprog` (minimizing the variance) in a loop in which I continuously change the expected returns of 10 portfolios to calculate the weights, will that be same as calling `frontcon` with the expected returns and 10 points?

Comment: Fascinating question! However, could you post example code that has prompted this question.  Also, how do you use the results of these computations?  I'm very interested in computational finance.

Comment: I can post more later but the main idea is that you have to minimize an equation (markowitz model) with constraints. Given a set of expected asset returns, covariances and an expected portfolio return, you can solve this with quadratic programming (quadprog function in matlab) to get the asset weights that will give you the portfolio with minimum risk. You can then continuously solve this by changing expected return to get what is called an "efficient frontier" (At least this is what I understood so far). My question is if frontcon is same as executing quadprog in a loop to get the frontier

Comment: They are from different toolboxes - so it would not be unusual for them to have overlapping / identical functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quadprog` and `frontcon` simply provide similar functionality, with the semantics of `frontcon` being easier for someone to use in the language of the Markowitz model.

In fact, if you dig under the hood a little (by using `edit`), you can see that `frontcon` calls `portopt` which eventually calls `quadprog`.